# how to create a pdf from a table created with angular material 7 virtual scrolling

Tags: jspdf, html2canvas, angular7, virtualscroll, angular-material-7

I want to create a pdf of a very big html table.

I  make use of angular material 7 virtual scroling to create that table.

Here is the html template code :

```
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="1" class="example-viewport">
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed" >
  <tbody id="test">
    <tr *cdkVirtualFor="let arrangement of final; let i = index" (click)="onSelected(i)" [class.selected]="selectionne[i]" class="example-item">
       <td><button mat-raised-button color="primary">No {{i+1}}</button></td>
       <td *ngFor="let element of arrangement">{{element}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and this is the component function in charge of creating the pdf:

```
exportAll(){
var data = document.getElementById('test'); 
html2canvas(data).then(canvas => {  
  // Few necessary setting options  
  var imgWidth = 208;   
  var pageHeight = 295;    
  var imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;  
  var heightLeft = imgHeight;  
  var position = 0;

  const contentDataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')  
  let pdf = new jspdf('p', 'mm', 'a4'); // A4 size page of PDF  

  pdf.addImage(contentDataURL, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
  pdf.addPage();  

  pdf.save('MYPdf.pdf'); // Generated PDF   
});}
```

The problem is that only (01) one page of less than 30 rows is created and the rest of the rows are left untouched.

**So, is this situation due to the fact that i'm using virtual scrolling to render the table?**

**What can i do to convert all my table into pdf?**

Answer (score 0):

Because the virtual scroll is simply replacing "ngFor" with "cdkVirtualFor", you could create an **ngTemplate** that you switch to when printing (set a variable/boolean before your exportAll() function).

when viewing...

```
<ng-container *ngIf="!print; else PRINTING"> 
   <tr *cdkVirtualFor="let arrangement of final; let i = index" ...
```

when printing...

```
<ng-template #PRINTING>
   <tr *ngFor="let arrangement of final; let i = index" ...
```